# How to use Config file between multiple pis

Tags: python, networking

I have multiple pi's running a program where they listen for a broadcast message and trigger a python script.

My python script that's triggered has config details that is same for all pi's.

Whenever I update any config option. I am reinstalling in all the pi's.

I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this. I am relatively new.. could you please direct how I can have a config file on network and share with all pi's.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone of the many suggestions should help you. Please accept one answer or make your own answer to finish your question so it will not pop up year for year.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are nearly limitless here:

- put the config file on a server and write a script which downloads it to the RPi when it boots up. Install the update script on each RPi
- put the config file on a server and modify your original script to use the config file directly from the server
- put the config file on a network drive and mount the drive on each RPi on boot
- create a custom package repo and put your config file in a package. Run `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` on each RPi to update the config
- configure passwordless SSH on your RPis and write a script which pushes the config file to all RPis from your PC
- configure a sync'd folder on each RPi with `rsync` or similar, and save the config file there
- broadcast the config file in the wake-up message

the list goes on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a network share for example made with **NFS** (network file system) or with **Samba** (MS windows like network share). Then you can make a symbolic link to the config file on the network share. I know that it is working with the Unix specific NFS. I don't know if symlink to a Samba share also works but it should. For example if you have a NFS share mounted to `/mnt/server/` that contains the central config file then you can symlink to it:

```
rpi ~$ ln -s /mnt/server/config.py config.py
```

Now you can use `config.py` like a normal local file.